# Spree + Model Override to change default order by

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

In Spree ( Rails based product ), I am trying to over-ride the model class but I am not getting the way to over-ride it. Here I want to change the default order by for one of the sql query.

```
Model Name : OptionType
```

Spree implemented new documentation and I am not able to search the appropriate answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For overriding optiontype model you will have to do the following

Create a file named option_type_decorator.rb

and put code like this

```
Spree::OptionType.class_eval do
 { your code }
end
```

Comment: I want to change the model name to something better suited to my purpose. Can we change the model name too?